# What's the origin of the phrase "seamy underbelly"?

Tags: phrases

What's the origin of the phrase "seamy underbelly"?

Example (my emphasis):

> With its large gay community, celebrity residents and beachfront cafés, Brighton is regarded as one of the hippest, most laid-back towns in Britain. But a glimpse of its **seamy underbelly** emerged last week as campaigners offered a £50,000 reward to find the killers of a 19-year-old girl sucked into a world of drugs and depravity.
>
> — Tony Thompson, The Observer, 2000

Comment: I always thought the expression was "seedy underbelly", and google seems to suggest that seedy is indeed quite a bit more popular. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: @painfulenglish - 'Seedy underbelly' is actually used with the same meaning as 'seamy underbelly. http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/seedy. 'Seedy' appears to be a bit more popular in that respect especially in BrE. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seamy+underbelly%2Cseedy+underbelly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseamy%20underbelly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseedy%20underbelly%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the results of the combination of two words used figuratively to refer euphemistically to the sordid part of something.  According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seamy%20underbelly&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseamy%20underbelly%3B%2Cc0) the expression is used from the 70's.

seamy (adj.): (from Etymonline)

> - c.1600, "least pleasant, worst," in figurative phrase seamy side, from seam + -y (2); the seamy side of a sewn garment being the less attractive, and thus typically turned in. **The popularity of the figurative sense likely is due to its use by Shakespeare in "Othello"** IV.ii.146: "Some such Squire he was That turn'd your wits the seamy-side without, And made you to suspect me with the Moore."

underbelly (noun):

> - c.1600, from under + belly (n.). *In figurative sense of "most vulnerable part" it is recorded from Churchill's 1942 speech*. **Sometimes used erroneously or euphemistically in sense of "seamy or sordid part" of anything.**